# Springboot Service throwing 404 after deployment in google app engine

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine

I have a springboot application which was working fine until yesterday, now after deployement which was only code to `Google App Engine` it stopped working and started throwing 404 not found for every api exposed.
when I try to access to default api like `https://project.com/` then its giving the result from mapped api, but when I try to access any other api like `https://project.com/test` it throws `404 not found` even api exists.
while everything is running in my local

Below is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>API</name>
<description> APIs</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <swagger.springdoc.openapi>1.4.1</swagger.springdoc.openapi>
    <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.3.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version><!-- {x-version-update:google-cloud-storage:current} -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.springdoc.openapi}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        &lt;!&ndash;<scope>provided</scope>&ndash;&gt;
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

     <!--<dependency>
         <groupId>mysql</groupId>
         <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
     </dependency>-->

    <!-- uncomment for server connection -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>                        <!-- Google Cloud Client Library for Java -->
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud</artifactId>
        <version>0.47.0-alpha</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>6.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opencensus</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencensus-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.24.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <version>1</version>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any help would be appriciated